# Error creating Docs with Sphinx and KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, python-sphinx, kivymd

I am making an app with KivyMD with python, now I want to make a quick documentation with Sphinx. But everytime I use "make html" on the command line I get the following error:

```
    WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'test'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc\importer.py", line 70, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\iuryck\OneDrive\Documents\VSCode\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivymd\app.py", line 62, in <module>
    class MDApp(App, FpsMonitoring):
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivymd\app.py", line 63, in MDApp
    theme_cls = ObjectProperty(ThemeManager())
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivymd\theming.py", line 860, in __init__
    self.rec_shadow = Atlas(f"{images_path}rec_shadow.atlas")
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\atlas.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._load()
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\atlas.py", line 216, in _load
    ci = CoreImage(subfilename)
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 561, in __init__
    self.filename = arg
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 754, in _set_filename
    image = ImageLoader.load(
  File "c:\users\iuryck\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 463, in load
    raise Exception('Unknown <%s> type, no loader found.' % ext)
Exception: Unknown <png> type, no loader found.
```

As you can see, Sphinx can find the Kivy module, and it can also find the code. So it's no directory problem or environment problem as I've seen alot.

It can be simply reproduced by installing KivyMD and Sphinx and using the following code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Hello World')
```

Then doing the normal sphinx documentation process on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't replicate. I ran your code after ensuring Sphinx and KivyMD were installed, ran `sphinx-quickstart` with all the defaults, then ran `make html` and it worked fine. This is on Win10 with Cygwin.

Comment: @MattDMo Did you install any dependencies or just straight pip install both? I'm on win 10 too. Maybe it's a problem with anaconda? I did run the terminal from anaconda terminal, made sure it was on the same environment and all.

Comment: I already had Sphinx and Kivy installed, with dependencies, I just had to pip install KivyMD, and all its dependencies were already there. I don't use Anaconda, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it. I'd uninstall both and try again from scratch, forcing dependencies to be updated.

Comment: Also, just looking at your error again, I'd recommend renaming your file from `test.py` to `kivymd_test.py` or something like that. It looks like something is trying to import a `test` module and it's importing your file instead.

Comment: @MattDMo I think you forgot the sphinx-apidoc -o [OUTPUT_DIR] [INPUT_DIR], otherwise it doesn' read your code. I did as you said and also got no errors, but it didn't document the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found 2 solutions, the error as far as I know comes from kivymd v0.104.1, so you can:

1- Update KivyMD to v0.104.2

But, if you have been working alot in a project like me, you will get a slight heart attack as you notice that alot of the visuals have changed from a version to another, alot of things look different and you probably do not want that, so, my solution to the problem was...

2- Modify the MDApp code at /kivymd/app.py

In v0.104.1 the MDApp class should look like this

```
class MDApp(App, FpsMonitoring):
    theme_cls = ObjectProperty(ThemeManager())
```

Remove the ThemeManager line, then add the following inside the class

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
```

So the whole thing should look like:

```
class MDApp(App, FpsMonitoring):
    theme_cls = ObjectProperty()
            
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
```

In case you wonder if this is safe and will not cause future errors, the /kivymd/app.py in version 0.104.2 looks exactly like this (hence where I got the ideia to do this). I ran my app, opened a bunch of pages and what not, had no problems, and visuals continue the same.